# How can I modify this regular expression to not allow white spaces?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regular expression which specifies characters the user is allowed to type:

```
@"^[A-Za-z0-9/!\$%\^&\*\(\)\-_\+\[\]\{\}\;\:\'\£\@\#\.\?]*$
```

I know '`\s`' is the character class for white space, but how do I add this to the regular expression so it excludes it? I have searched for this on Stack Overflow - the questions provide solutions to exclude white space but not how to use it in an existing regular expression. If I add it like I have the other characters, it would mean 'allow white space'?

Edit: Not sure why this has been marked down? Thanks to everyone for their answers

Comment: Does it currently accept white space?

Comment: I've tested it just to be sure, and as I thought - it already does exclude white spaces...

Comment: What do you mean by `excludes it`? Currently your regex (which BTW doesnt need so many escape characters - you only need to escape the `[` and `]` in the character class) does not allow whitespace so it's already excluded.

Comment: @Oded, no you can use `\s` also inside a character class.

Comment: @Jamiec, he should also escape the `-`, since its in the middle of the character class.

Comment: @stema - no need to escape `-` in a char class. (Tested using expresso & .NET regex).

Comment: @Jamiec `-` is a special character inside a character class, it denotes a character range. [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: @JamieC: presumably it depends on where you use it. If you did something like [0-9] and you jsut wanted 0, - and 9 then you'd want to escape it. That's an obvious example but it may be that some consider it best practice to always escape it to prevent any kind of ambiguity... You're right though that is doesn't always need to be escaped. :)

Comment: It doesn't accept white space now.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need all those escapes.
Second of all, the regex already doesn't allow whitespaces.

```
@"^[A-Za-z0-9\[\]/!$%^&*()\-_+{};:'£@#.?]*$"
```

The [] define a set of characters to allow (followed by * means that characters from the characters set can be zero or more times).

^ matches the beginning and $ matches the end, so the fact that /s isn't anywhere there, means white spaces won't be allowed.

Comment: (You've still got it in your description)

Comment: the dash needs escaping inside a character class, or move it to the start or the end of the class. Here it would allow any character from the ASCII table from `)` to `_` (that includes also the `-`)

Comment: @stema Thanks for pointing that out. I've missed a lot of things in my answer >.>

Answer (score 3):

In regex `^` within the square brackets indicates negation so adding `^\s` would mean "not whitespace."

Comment: Not strictly true, a `^` at the *start* of a character class is a negated class. `^` in the middle somewhere (like the OP) just included that character in the character class.

Answer (score 0):

In the regular expression, if you don't write "\s". This means your regular expression doesn't allow any blank spaces.

For example:
1) If I don't want to allow any user to enter blank space in the text box, then the regular expression is written as:

Regex alphabet=new Regex(@"^[a-z]*$");

2) If the user is allowed to enter any blank space in the text box then the regular expression is written as:

Regex alphabet=new Regex(@"^[a-z\s]*$");

3) In regular expression " ^ " means beginning and " $ " means end.

NOTE: ^\s means negation of "\s"

Regex regfname = new Regex(@"^[^\s][a-zA-Z]*$");

this code will not allow any blank spaces and no empty text box!

I hope this will help you to understand the concept of blank spaces in regular expression..

Comment: The OP already understands the purpose of  `\s`: what they needed was advice on its use in their specific regex pattern.  Your question doesn't address that, and so it's not very helpful.