# How disallow space, blank, ("_") charachter from text box input by keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, keypress

How disallow space, blank, (`"_"`) character from text box input by keyboard (WPF, C#)?

I try by code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9\[\]/!$%^&*()\-_+{};:'£@#.?]*$");
```

but this part of code disallow all character, but not space.

Comment: Also I try with ␣ , but nothing is chaged. Text box and so on accept space in text box

Comment: [Dublicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410882/how-can-i-modify-this-regular-expression-to-not-allow-white-spaces)?

Comment: if you wanted to do while typing than ... use `KeyPress` event and if Key is 32 or Key.Space then e.Handled = true;

Comment: `_` is an underscore, not a blank btw.

Answer (score 6):

You can add `PreviewKeyDown` handler:

```
private void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Now your textbox will ignore spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your goal, another option is to handle `PreviewTextInput`:

```
 {
      //...
      TextBox tb = new TextBox(); 
      tb.PreviewTextInput += Tb_PreviewTextInput;
 } 

 private void Tb_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Text == " ") 
         e.Handled = true; 
     base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
 }
```

For example, if you want to stop copy paste space, this is recommended.

On the other hand, if you are pointing to a situation that you want to remove all spaces from the text before inserting to the TextBox, the following might help:

```
    // ...
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();  
    tb.TextChanged += Tb_TextChanged;
    // ...

    bool _changing;
    private void Tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_changing)
            return;
        _changing = true;
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        string tx = tb.Text;
        while (tx.Contains(" "))
            tx = tx.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        tb.Text = tx;
        _changing = false;
    }
```

In this case, see [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234703/WPF-TextBox-with-PreviewTextChanged-event-for-filt), too.

Comment: PreviewTextInput does not get triggered on a space.  This first solutions will not work.